# How to derive a parent-child table from a hierarchical table using R?

Tags: r, tree, hierarchical-data

I'm attempting to use the `collapsibleTree` htmlwidget which requires a dataframe containing a row for each node, i.e. containing all parent-child relationships (known as a DataFrameNetwork in `data.tree` parlance I believe) in order to take advantage of some of the more useful features.

I am however starting with a dataframe containing a row for each leaf (known as a DataFrameTable?) and am struggling to get it in the right format. I believe the easiest thing to do is to use the `data.tree` package, but I'm open to suggestions, particularly if they're tidyverse orientated and avoid looping.

Example:

data:

```
lev1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C")
lev2 = c("a", letters[1:5])
lev3 = 1:6
df <- data.frame(lev1, lev2, lev3)
```

target:

```
result <- data.frame(parent = c(lev1, lev2),
                     child = c(lev2, lev3)) %>% unique()
```

(Awful code I know). This particular example has three levels in the hierarchy, but I need the solution to be general enough to apply to any number of levels. I've tried adding a pathString to the dataframe as per the documentation and following up with `FromDataFrameTable()` and then `ToDataFrameNetwork()` but I get the feeling I'm going about things all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

rbindlist(lapply(as.data.frame(rollapply(names(df), 2, c), stringsAsFactors = F), 
                 function(x) select(df, c(x)))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("parent", "child"))
```

Output is:

```
    parent child
 1:      A     a
 2:      A     b
 3:      B     c
 4:      B     d
 5:      C     e
 6:      a     1
 7:      a     2
 8:      b     3
 9:      c     4
10:      d     5
11:      e     6
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(lev1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), lev2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
    lev3 = 1:6), .Names = c("lev1", "lev2", "lev3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have generalized above code from comment, using a loop.
will work on a tidyverse solution later today.

change to a matrix form

```
df_mat <- as.matrix(df)
```

define an empty traget matrix as output

```
df_output <- matrix(nrow=0,ncol=2)
```

loop

```
for (i in 1:(ncol(df_mat)-1))
{
  df_output <- rbind(df_output,df_mat[,c(i,i+1)])
}
```

change to a dataframe

```
df_output <- as.data.frame(df_output)
```

assign meaningful column names

```
colnames(df_output) <- c("Parent","Child")
```

Output

```
df_output
```